# Texture Loading Problems with OpenGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

Okay, let me preface this by saying that I am very new to OpenGL as it pertains to Android, and while I've been reading up on it for some time, I cannot get past this roadblock in my coding.

Currently I am trying to write a class to load textures from .png file located in my drawables folder onto a .obj model that I made in Blender. I did a UV unwrap on the Blender model, and then used the uv unwrap as a guide for the .png file.

The issue currently is that I am able to load the texture onto the model, but it is one solid color which seems to be coming from the texture file. Clearly I don't understand enough about UV texturing in Blender, but there are so many different OpenGL libraries, and so much variation from PC to Android that it's really hard to wrap my head around what works where.

I would be extremely grateful if somebody could help me with this. Here's some of the relevant code, I'll post more as necessary:

from TextureLoader:

```
public Texture getTexture(GL10 gl, final int ref) throws IOException {
    Texture tex = (Texture) table.get(ref);

    if (tex != null) {
        return tex;
    }

    Log.i("Textures:", "Loading texture: " + ref);

    tex = getTexture(gl, ref,
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, // target
            GL10.GL_RGBA,     // dst pixel format
            GL10.GL_LINEAR, // min filter (unused)
            GL10.GL_NEAREST);

    table.put(ref,tex);

    return tex;
}

public Texture getTexture(GL10 gl, final int ref,
                            int target, 
                            int dstPixelFormat, 
                            int minFilter, 
                            int magFilter)  throws IOException {
    if (!sReady) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Texture Loader not prepared");
    }

    int srcPixelFormat = 0;

    // create the texture ID for this texture 
    int id = createID(gl);
    Texture texture = new Texture(target, id);

    // bind this texture 
    gl.glBindTexture(target, id); 

    Bitmap bitmap = loadImage(ref);  
    texture.setWidth(bitmap.getWidth());
    texture.setHeight(bitmap.getHeight());

    if (bitmap.hasAlpha()) {
        srcPixelFormat = GL10.GL_RGBA;
    } else {
        srcPixelFormat = GL10.GL_RGB;
    }

 // convert that image into a byte buffer of texture data 
    ByteBuffer textureBuffer = convertImageData(bitmap); 

    if (target == GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D) { 
        gl.glTexParameterf(target, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, minFilter); 
        gl.glTexParameterf(target, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, magFilter); 
    } 

    GLUtils.texImage2D(target, 0, bitmap, 0);
    /*gl.glTexImage2D(target, 
                      0, 
                      dstPixelFormat, 
                      get2Fold(bitmap.getWidth()), 
                      get2Fold(bitmap.getHeight()), 
                      0, 
                      srcPixelFormat, 
                      GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                      textureBuffer);*/

    bitmap.recycle();

    return texture;
  }

/**
 * Get the closest greater power of 2 to the fold number
 * 
 * @param fold The target number
 * @return The power of 2
 */
private int get2Fold(int fold) {
    int ret = 2;
    while (ret < fold) {
        ret *= 2;
    }
    return ret;
}

/**
 * Convert the buffered image to a texture
 *
 * @param bufferedImage The image to convert to a texture
 * @param texture The texture to store the data into
 * @return A buffer containing the data
 */
private ByteBuffer convertImageData(Bitmap bitmap) { 
    ByteBuffer imageBuffer = null;

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] data = stream.toByteArray();

    imageBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length); 
    imageBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); 
    imageBuffer.put(data, 0, data.length); 
    imageBuffer.flip();

    return imageBuffer; 
}

/**
 * Creates an integer buffer to hold specified ints
 * - strictly a utility method
 *
 * @param size how many int to contain
 * @return created IntBuffer
 */
protected IntBuffer createIntBuffer(int size) {
  ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * size);
  temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

  return temp.asIntBuffer();
}

private Bitmap loadImage(int ref) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    Matrix flip = new Matrix();
    flip.postScale(1f, -1f);

    // This will tell the BitmapFactory to not scale based on the device's pixel density:
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inScaled = false;

    Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(sContext.getResources(), ref, opts);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(temp, 0, 0, temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), flip, true);
    temp.recycle();

    return bitmap;
}
```

from Texture:

```
public void bind(GL10 gl) {
  gl.glBindTexture(target, textureID);
  gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

as it is called:

```
public void render() {
    //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
      gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
      gl.glPushMatrix();

      gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -1.2f, z); //Move down 1.2 Unit And Into The Screen 6.0
      gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //X
      gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //Y

      texture.bind(gl);
      model.draw(gl);

      gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```